# Regexp strangely not working

Tags: javascript, regex, string, node.js

I tested the following code with a regexp inside and the console log is printing null. Here's the code :

```
var decRegexp = new RegExp("[0-9]{2}-(\\n)*\s*[A-Z]{1,3}-(\\n)?\s*[0-9]{2,3}", "g");
var textToTest = "n° 14-\n      DCC-71 du du 4 juin 2014"
var decisionNumberMatches = textToTest.match(decRegexp);
console.log(decisionNumberMatches);
```

Seriously, I don't understand why it's not returning me "n° 14-\n      DCC-71 du du 4 juin 2014". I tested this regexp on http://jsregex.com/ and it works, so maybe it's a strange behaviour of nodejs.

Answer (score 4):

A `\` in a [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) must be escaped as `\\`.

That's one of the reasons why you shouldn't use a string to create a regexp from a constant expression.

Use a [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression) :

```
var decRegexp = /[0-9]{2}-(\\n)*\s*[A-Z]{1,3}-(\\n)?\s*[0-9]{2,3}/g;
```

(another reason is you get better performances with regex literals)

Answer (score 0):

`RegExp` object requires you to double escape the escape sequence so use:

```
var decRegexp = new RegExp("[0-9]{2}-(\\n)*\\s*[A-Z]{1,3}-(\\n)?\\s*[0-9]{2,3}", "g");
```

Comment: It's actually the _String_ being passed into the _RegExp_ constructor that is requiring the escaping of backslashes

Comment: Yes that's true and that's what I meant.